# Sketching level curves of a function for given values

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

For $f(x,y)=\ln(x-y)$, sketch the level curves for the values $k=-1,0,1$

If we set $f(x,y)=k$, then for the values $k=-1,0,1:$

$$
y=
\begin{cases}
x-e^{-1}\\
x-1\\
x-e^{}
\end{cases}
$$

Graphing these gives:

[image]

Comment: For me it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\ln(x-y)=k
$$

$$
x-y=e^{k}
$$

$$
y=x-e^{k}
$$

Therefore, the level curves are straight lines with the slope of $1$ and $y$-intercept $-e^k$